# Why is this contenteditable div caret (blinking cursor) jumping to the beginning when hitting max length?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field with a max character limit set and when the input reaches the max limit the ending characters will be removed. The issue is when the limit is reached, the caret will jump back to the beginning of the text and not the end. This also happens when inserting in between the text.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can make the caret appear on the end of the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/mLop29rv/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="usertitle-editable" class="title-contenteditable maxlength-contenteditable" placeholder="enter input here" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" type="text" ></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#usertitle-editable").keyup(function(event) {
  var text = document.getElementById('usertitle-editable').innerHTML;
    if (text.length > 3)
    document.getElementById('usertitle-editable').innerHTML = (text.substring(0, 3));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more concise way, but here is a solution to move the cursor to the end of the text by using 
`document.createRange()` and `window.getSelection()`
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spliffmon/bytz46ms/40/)